# Flutter Algolia Search Pagination

Tags: flutter

I can use Algolia in Flutter project! But can’t make pagination (`setHitsPerPage`, `setPage`).
can anyone help me?
can you write me an example for pagination?

Comment: Provide some code what you have tried which is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is never too late to answer so i just discovered that i wasn't able to fetch results from Algolia by using 'page', so i checked the code of AGOLIA flutter plugin and came to know that you have to call methods on AlgoliaQuery in chain manner. Following is the example

```
AlgoliaQuery query =
  Constants.algolia.instance.index(Constants.ALGOLIA_MAIN_INDEX);

query
      .setHitsPerPage(10)
      .setPage(_currentPage)
      .getObjects()
      .then((algoliaSnapshot) {}
```